# Fundamental solution to 2D Diffusion Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I was reading about the diffusion equation $$-\frac{1}{D}\frac{\partial p(x,y,t)}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}p(x,y,t)+\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y^2}p(x,y,t)=0$$ where D is a constant.
This has an analytical fundamental solution of
$$p(x,y,t)=\frac{1}{4\pi D t}\exp\frac{-(x+y)^2}{(4Dt)}$$
(Source: http://rpdata.caltech.edu/courses/aph162/2006/Protocols/diffusion.pdf)

I was thinking that the solution to the similar equation where we take $D=1$ and introduce a constant $A$,
$$-\frac{\partial p(x,y,t)}{\partial t}+A\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}p(x,y,t)+A\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y^2}p(x,y,t)=0$$
would be something like $$p(x,y,t)=\frac{1}{4\pi At}\exp\frac{-(x+y)^2}{(4At)}$$

But that doesn't seem to work out. I am hoping someone can help me find the actual solution. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be $-(x^2 + y^2)$ not $-(x + y)^2$.

Comment: Oh thank you so much. I appreciate the help. :)